# Getting hardware information using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, hardware

Is it possible to get hardware informations using javascript in a way that is compatible with all the browsers and operating systems?

Comment: What kind of hardware information?

Comment: Information like Processor type, harddisk capacity, cpu type, serial number...

Comment: You can get Graphics Card make/model as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267764/how-to-get-the-video-card-driver-name-using-javascript-browser-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

This is information that the browser does not expose to the javascript engine (if it even look it up at all).

Comment: How about using ActiveXObject to lookup?

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/

Comment: @gviswanathan ActiveX doesn't work in all browsers and also not on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for comments.

I tried ActiveXObject ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") activexobject in InternetExplorer it works fine, do we have any alternatives for rest of the browsers like (Firefox, Chrome)

Comment: @gviswanathan - No, no alternative for other browsers. Perhaps writing  your own plugins/add-ins - and these would have to get installed on every client computer.